# Apparent Deadlock creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks using JPA2.0 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

1)  We are using JPA2.0 and Hibernate 4.2 and we initially implemented database connection using Hibernate default connection pool. We thought this was the issue for outofmemory error, and we were also seeing  Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!) in the logs

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

2)  So implemented C3P0 connection pool see below persistence.xml file and also changes in tomcat service to set JAVA_OPTS.

```
From - JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
To – JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2G -Xms1G -XX:NewSize=500m -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40"

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="pub-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
value="jdbc:informix-sqli://fddb.fd.gtwy.dcn:7101/fd_test:INFORMIXSERVER=fd_ecf" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="dcapps" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="1000" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="30" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="60"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.auto_close_session" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads" value="3"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
```

3)  And we ran into this issue (see below) so I have changed the log4j level to WARN to ignore Info messages.

```
2013-11-21 17:09:46 INFO  SQLWarnings:43 - Database has transactions
java.sql.SQLWarning: Database has transactions
    at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:125)
    at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:149)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.a(IfxSqliConnect.java:2272)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.t(IfxSqliConnect.java:4542)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.b(IfxSqliConnect.java:3100)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.a(IfxSqliConnect.java:2973)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.c(IfxSqli.java:2843)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeOpenDatabase(IfxSqli.java:2034)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1622)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:254)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2013-11-21 17:09:46 INFO  SQLWarnings:43 - Database selected
java.sql.SQLWarning: Database selected
    at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:125)
    at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:149)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.a(IfxSqliConnect.java:2272)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.t(IfxSqliConnect.java:4548)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.b(IfxSqliConnect.java:3100)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.a(IfxSqliConnect.java:2973)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.c(IfxSqli.java:2843)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeOpenDatabase(IfxSqli.java:2034)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1622)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:254)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2013-11-21 17:09:46 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:73 - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
```

4)  We had this issue(see below) and it was also complaining about “too many files open”, so to fix this we have changed the ulimit to 4096 this fixed the issue.
Tomcat is attempting to save information about the application for use at startup and that info is being stored in the SESSIONS.ser
5)  Now we are running into this issue(see below) after trying to test the reports(load test) even though it’s a warning message it still bring down the application performance , tomcat is too slow after these exceptions.

```
2013-11-25 16:39:12 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:608 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2bb8cbc9 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2013-11-25 16:39:12 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:624 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2bb8cbc9 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@714b0f8b (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@76e9a8c8 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@66481f75 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9096ec9
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@4a4852c1
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@52312300
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@17f0ff28
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@4effa75f
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7245767d
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@2e664327
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@3bc2cd3d
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@72307e71
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@4dbd6748
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@4dc7cfd7
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@791e5425
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@36268742
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1b7a19d4
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6d35bb63
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@62a19898
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@5f2955be
Pool thread stack traces:
```

6)  To fix this issue we have used Google help and have added properties to persistence.xml but I still see the same exception

```
We have Set this to zero
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />

Added these properties
<property name="hibernate.auto_close_session" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="60"/>
```